# TableLayoutPanel cell border issue

Tags: c#, .net, tablelayoutpanel

I have `TableLayoutPanel` placed on windows form.
It has 3 columns and 2 rows.
I have set CellBorderStyle property of TableLayoutPanel to "Single".
I want to hide second column dynamically.
To achieving this I have write following code:

```
tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles[0].Width = 0;
```

But then `TableLayoutPanel` will look like below.See the border, border becomes thick:
[image]
Can anyone resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

You will need to owner.draw the TLP:

Hiding the 3rd column:[image]

This is a way: Turn off the `CellBorder` and code this event

```
private void tableLayoutPanel1_CellPaint(object sender, TableLayoutCellPaintEventArgs e)
{
    Rectangle r = e.CellBounds;
    using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.DarkGoldenrod))
    {
        // top and left lines
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, r.X, r.Y, r.X + r.Width, r.Y);
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, r.X, r.Y, r.X, r.Y + r.Height);
        // last row? move hor.lines 1 up!
        int cy = e.Row == tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount - 1 ? -1 : 0;
        if (cy != 0) e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, r.X, r.Y + r.Height + cy, 
                                r.X + r.Width, r.Y + r.Height + cy);
        // last column ? move vert. lines 1 left!
        int cx = e.Column == tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount - 1 ? -1 : 0;
        if (cx != 0) e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, r.X + r.Width + cx, r.Y, 
                                r.X + r.Width + cx, r.Y + r.Height);
    }
}
```

But you should rather ask yourself why the situation has arisen and if the user shouldn't maybe actually see the there is a column hidden..